# Seeking a Lyapunov function for a SIR model with immunity loss

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, asymptotics, stability, epidemics-modeling

We add the immunity loss to the SIR model and obtain the following autonomous system.
$$
\begin{align}
s' &= -is+\alpha r \\
i' &= i s - \gamma i\\
r' &= \gamma i-\alpha r
\end{align}
\tag1
$$
with $$(s+i+r)\big|_{t=0}=1,\ s(0)\ge0,\ i(0)\ge0,\ r(0)\ge0,$$
where prime denotes derivative w.r.t. time, $s,i,r$ represent the proportion of “susceptible”, “infected” and “recovered” individuals, $\beta$ is the kinetic constant of infectiousness, $\gamma$ that of recovery, and $\alpha$ the speed of the immunity loss. Suppose all the coefficients are positive. It is easy to supply the candidates for the long term ($t\to\infty$) asymptotic steady solution, which is to simply set the derivatives on the left hand side of the differential equations to zero, and obtain two solutions.
$$s_\infty=1,\ i_\infty=0,\ r_\infty=0;\tag2$$
or
$$s_\infty=\min(\gamma,1),\ i_\infty=\frac{(1-\gamma)_+}{1+\frac\gamma\alpha},\ r_\infty=\frac{(1-\gamma)_+}{1+\frac\alpha\gamma}.\tag3$$
I conjecture that Solution (2) is achieved either when the initial condition is exactly that, and that Solution (3) is achieved under all other conditions.

The function
${\scr L}(s,i)=s-s_\infty\ln s+w(i-i_\infty \ln i)$ for some positive $w$ seems to fail to play the role of a Lyapunov function. What is an appropriate Lyapunov function for this autonomous ODE?

Comment: What do the eigenvalues of linearized system look like at the two fixed points?

Comment: @PiyushGrover: I looked at it first but was deterred by the apparent complexity for the second fixed point. I will examine it in detail more. Do the eigenvalue help in finding an appropriate Lyapunov function?

Comment: It will help clarify your conjecture (it could be true if all eigenvalues for 2 are non-negative and for 3 are non-positive). In any case, you cannot have a global lyapunov function simply because 2 is a fixed point and hence 3 cannot be globally stable fixed point.

Comment: @PiyushGrover: I have put in the local stability analysis. Please review. Are you saying if there are more than one fixed points, there can not exist a global Lyapunov even if one is not locally stable and the second one is locally stable?

Comment: @PiyushGrover: Even if there are two locally stable fixed points, we should be able to construct a Lyapunov function just for a specified (compact) domain containing a unique locally stable fixed point, right?

Comment: Yes, you can have local lyapunov function, but not global even if the other fixed point is unstable.

Comment: For global stability of a fixed point (say 3 here), you need derivative of Lyapunov function to be negative definite everywhere. However, any function you pick will have derivative zero at the "other" fixed point (2).

Comment: @PiyushGrover: Yes. I just came back to say the same. Now, since Fixed Point $(2)$ is right on the boundary of the domain of definition $s+i\le1,\ s\ge0,\ i\ge0$, could there be a global Lyapunov function in the interior?

Comment: I believe if (2) has all eigenvalues with positive real parts, then it is possible. The trace is not enough to judge that.

Comment: @PiyushGrover: You are right. I was lazy and trying to be clever looking only at the trace. One has to examine the eigenvalues themselves. I have edited my local stability analysis. Please review. Fixed Point (2) is unstable for $\gamma<1$. So there is no global stability for Fixed Point (3) in the interior of the domain of definition. Is there a maximal open domain with containing Fixed Point (3) such that Fixed Point (3) is globally asympstotically stable in that open domain?

Comment: I don't see how the first two equations form the largest set of independent equations because $s'$ depends on $r$ so you need the third equation as well?

Comment: @SampleTime: $r=1-s-i$.

Comment: @Hans But only at $t = 0$, at least that is what you wrote in the question. Is this equation supposed to hold  for all $t$?

Comment: If so, the characteristic polynomial is $\alpha(1 - \gamma)s^2 + \frac{\alpha (\alpha + 1)}{\alpha + \gamma} s + 1$ so this confirms your result $0 <\gamma < 1$ because otherwise some coefficients would be negative.

Comment: @SampleTime: Adding all three equations in $(1)$, you get $(s+i+r)'=0$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification I didn't notice that. Then you can just use the characteristic polynomial since for a second order system that is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We examine the local stability of this system. Since the first two equations of System $(1)$ form the largest set of independent equations, the Jacobian of this system is
$$J(s,i) := \begin{bmatrix}
-i-\alpha & -s-\alpha \\
i & s-\gamma
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

At Fixed Point $(3)$, the eigenvalues are 
$$x=-\frac{1+\alpha}{2(1+\frac\gamma\alpha)}(1\pm\sqrt{1-4\delta}),\quad \delta:=\frac{1-\gamma}\alpha\Big(\frac{\alpha+\gamma}{1+\alpha}\Big)^2.$$
$\gamma<1\iff\delta>0\implies \mathbf{Re}(1\pm\sqrt{1-4\delta})>0$. So the system is locally stable there.

At Fixed Point $(2)$, the eigenvalues are
$$x_1:=-\alpha,\ x_2:=1-\gamma.$$
For $\gamma<1$, the fixed point is locally unstable.

Therefore, as Piyush Grover suggests in his comment above, the system is not globally stable for the domain $\big\{(s,i)\,\big|\,s+i\le1,s\ge0, i\ge0, (s,i)\ne(1,0)\big\}$ when $\gamma<1$.